# In which condition we will make Child class abstract rather than Parent in java?

Tags: java

In which condition we will go this approach?

```
 class Parent{

       public void relation(){
        }
  }
 abstract class Child extends Parent{

       public abstract void relation();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only be useful if we never want the parent class method definition used in child class  and which so ever extends abstract class have to give its own method defination

Comment: Yeah! you are true @UserSx. But can you give me a real time example for more clarification?